# Add functions to nuxt.config.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

Basically I have an app and on generate, I generate all pages, a sitemap and a RSS feed currently though I have to make the same axios call 3 times

like so

**nuxt.config.js**

```
generate: {
    routes: function() {
        return axios.get(data)
            .then(res => {
            ... 
            })
    }
},
sitemap: {
    routes: function() {
        return axios.get(data)
            .then(res => {
            ... 
            })
    }
},
feed: {
   etc...
}
```

now Is there a way I can call the data once and feed it to each of these module methods?? I tried putting some functions at the top of the nuxt.config.js but I was getting errors on generate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try saving the promise into a variable for re-use, eg

```js
const routesPromise = axios.get(data).then(({ data }) => data)

// snip

generate: {
  routes () {
    return routesPromise.then(data => {
      // ...
    })
},
sitemap: {
  routes () {
    return routesPromise.then(data => {
      // ...
    })
  }
},
// etc
```

---

Adding `.then()` calls to the promise won't modify the original resolved value so you can keep using it as many times as you want while only making a single HTTP request.